# Invalid CFML construct found when using cf.query and cf.http

Tags: http, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to learn cf.http and cf.query from [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-79a8.html).

I tried following code:

```
<cfscript>
    result = CF.http({method:"get", url:"http://google.com" });
</cfscript>
<cfdump var="#result#">
```

But I get error:

> Invalid CFML construct found on line 2 at column 33.

FYI: my coldfusion server version: 9,0,1,274733

What would be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Peter touched on, the code you have provided is a mishmash of some sample ACTIONSCRIPT code, mixed in with CFML.  This is never going to work.

The page you point to in the docs is about writing server-side ActionScript.  If that's actually what you're trying to do (I suspect not) then you need to follow through the rest of the docs, starting from here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-5df0.html.

If you're just trying to learn how to use Http.cfc and Query.cfc, then you should look at the correct part of the docs:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSe9cbe5cf462523a0693d5dae123bcd28f6d-8000.html

But no matter what you do, you can't mix ActionScript and CFML in the same file like that.

Answer (score 7):

Check the ColdFusion docs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSe9cbe5cf462523a0693d5dae123bcd28f6d-7ff8.html and this [blog post](http://mikehodgson.com/cfhttp-in-pure-cfscript/).

There's no `CF` prefix, it's a stateful object created using the `new` keyword, and no struct literal syntax in the constructor - just pass name value pairs.

```
<cfscript>
httpService = new http(url="http://www.google.com", method="get");
result = httpService.send().getPrefix();
writeDump(result);
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Yeah, but I could not understand why it is there in docs? see second last tree node [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/index.html)

Comment: The link provided didn't send me to a specific page in the livedocs.

Comment: CF.stuff is ActionScript, not CFML. This link should go directly to a relevant page: http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/SSActionScript_14.html (Adobe LiveDocs really does suck!)

Comment: @Vikas: following your link, expand the `Script Functions Implemented as CFCs` node and click `http` under there.

Comment: @orangepips: your answer is absolutely correct, But I don't need solution But I want to know why CF.http not worked, as you said, if it is a state full object, then how to create it? why it is not explained in docs?

Comment: In cf.http, you can also set CGI, is it true? can we also set it in `<cfhttp />` tag also?

Comment: @Vikas: `CF` doesn't work because ColdFusion does not name space objects. You  create it using the `new` keyword as shown in the example above. You can pass along CGI variables using `http` or `<cfhttp/>` as parameters, see this blog post: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/903-Passing-Referer-AS-ColdFusion-CFHttp-CGI-Value-vs-HEADER-Value-.htm

Answer (score 0):

Re: the "Invalid CFML construct". It's worth noting, this:

```
http({method:"get", url:"http://google.com" });
```

should have been this:

```
http(method:"get", url:"http://google.com");
```

or this

```
http(argumentCollection={method="get", url="http://google.com"});
```

You can define structures using `{key:"value"}`, `{key="value"}` and `{"key"="value"}`.

(If you wrap the key in quotes, it will be case sensitive when dumped or serialized)

You can call methods using `function("value")`, `function(key:"value")`, `function(key="value")` and `function(key1={key2="value2"})`

If you want to nest structures you must use the `{key="value"}` or `{"key"="value"}` style.
eg. `{"key1"={key2="value2"}}`

You can even mix arrays and structs. `{key1={"key2"=["a","b","c"]}}`

Ben Nadel's blog post sums it up.

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1993-Using-Dynamic-Keys-In-ColdFusion-9-s-Implicit-Struct-Creation.htm